# Selecting one from radio group value and scrolling down and some item selected automatically in Recycler View( beginner)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am making an attendance system where I take the attendance using RadioGroup with two options. When I select some radio button and scroll down some other radio button gets auto-selected. If I change them upper ones also get changed.

**Main class**

```
public class TeacherAttendanceActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AttendanceAdapter.AttendanceAdapterListner {

    public static TeacherAttendanceActivity  teacherAttendanceActivity;
    private static final String TAG = TeacherAttendanceActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    List<AttendanceModel> listItems;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    private AttendanceAdapter attendanceAdapter;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;

    private SearchView searchView;
    Button btnSubmit;
    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
    // date
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

    String class_id,title;
    Boolean Error;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_teacher_attendance);
        //get data from intent
        class_id = super.getIntent().getExtras().getString("id"); //class_id
        title = super.getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Class: "+title+", Date: "+currentDateandTime );



        // SqLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
        // session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        btnSubmit=findViewById(R.id.buttonAttendanceSubmit);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Error=false;
                Gson gson=new Gson();
                final String newDataArray=gson.toJson(listItems); // dataarray is list aaray

                    for (int i = 0; i < AttendanceAdapter.listItems.size(); i++){
                    if(AttendanceAdapter.listItems.get(i).getAttendance()==null){
                        Toast.makeText(TeacherAttendanceActivity.this, "Check attendance at roll:"+AttendanceAdapter.listItems.get(i).getRoll(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Error =true;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                if (!Error){
                    request(class_id,currentDateandTime,newDataArray);
                }

            }
        });


        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        attendanceAdapter = new AttendanceAdapter(listItems, this, (AttendanceAdapter.AttendanceAdapterListner) this);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_attendance);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(TeacherAttendanceActivity.this));
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        teacherAttendanceActivity = this;
        //refresh_list(class_id);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        refresh_list(class_id);
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttendanceAdapterSelected(AttendanceModel model) {

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.refresh, menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tool_bar, menu);

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sittings",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_logout:
                logoutUser();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_about:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"About",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_devinfo:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Dev info",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.refresh:
                refresh_list(class_id);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);
        db.deleteUsers();
        // Launching the login activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // refresh list
    public void refresh_list(String id) {
        // this method refresh list and get the json data
        listItems.clear();
        // adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems,getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(attendanceAdapter);

        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, ApiConfig.URL_TEACHER_ATTENDANCE+id, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                try {

                    progressDialog.hide();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Data");  // finding data
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(jsonObject));

                    int len = jsonArray.length();
                    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        AttendanceModel item = new AttendanceModel(
                                o.getString("id"),
                                o.getString("name"),
                                o.getString("roll"),
                                o.getString("class_id"),
                                o.getString("status"),
                                null
                        );
                        listItems.add(item);

                        //adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems,getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(attendanceAdapter);   // setting them in list view

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.hide();
                Toast.makeText(TeacherAttendanceActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            /** Passing some request headers* */
            @Override
            public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
                HashMap<String,String> userDetail= db.getUserDetails();
                String userToken = userDetail.get("token");
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(userToken));
                HashMap headers = new HashMap();
                headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer "+userToken);
                return headers;
            }
        };
        stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
        VolleyRequest.getInstance(TeacherAttendanceActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }

    // take attendance
    private void request( final String classId,final String date,final String data ) {

        progressDialog.setMessage("Taking attendance");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                ApiConfig.URL_TEACHER_ATTENDANCE_STORE, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response);
                hideDialog();
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        String attendance = jObj.getString("Attendance");
                        Toast.makeText(TeacherAttendanceActivity.this, attendance, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();

                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("message");
                        Toast.makeText(TeacherAttendanceActivity.this,
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(TeacherAttendanceActivity.this, "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(TeacherAttendanceActivity.this,
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            /** Passing some request headers* */
            @Override
            public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(TeacherAttendanceActivity.this);
                HashMap<String,String> userDetail= db.getUserDetails();
                String userToken = userDetail.get("token");
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(userToken));
                HashMap headers = new HashMap();
                headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer "+userToken);
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("class_id", classId);
                params.put("date", date);
                params.put("data", data);

                return params;
            }

        };
        strReq.setShouldCache(false);
        // Adding request to request queue
        VolleyRequest.getInstance(TeacherAttendanceActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(strReq);
    }
    private void showDialog() {
        if (!progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }


}
```

***Model class***
'model class for convenient  '

```
public class AttendanceModel {
    String id,name,roll,classId,previousAttendance,attendance;


    public AttendanceModel(String id, String name,String roll, String classId,String previousAttendance,String attedance ){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.classId =classId;
        this.roll=roll;
        this.attendance=attedance;
        this.previousAttendance=previousAttendance;
    }

    public String getAttendance() {
        return attendance;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }
    public String getClassId() {
        return classId;
    }
    public String getPreviousAttendance(){return previousAttendance;}

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setRoll(String roll) {
        this.roll = roll;
    }

    public void setClassId(String classId) {
        this.classId = classId;
    }

    public void setPreviousAttendance(String previousAttendance) {
        this.previousAttendance = previousAttendance;
    }

    public void setAttendance(String attendance) {
        this.attendance = attendance;
    }

 
}
```

***Adapter class***
' adapter class '

```
public class AttendanceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AttendanceAdapter.ViewHolder>  implements Filterable

{
    // date
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

    private static final String TAG = AttendanceAdapter.class.getSimpleName();


    public static List<AttendanceModel> listItems;
    private List<AttendanceModel> listItemsFiltered;
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private AttendanceAdapter.AttendanceAdapterListner listner;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    public static JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    public static JSONArray ja  = new JSONArray();




    public AttendanceAdapter(List<AttendanceModel> listItems, Context context, AttendanceAdapter.AttendanceAdapterListner listner) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.listner=listner;
        this.context = context;
        this.listItemsFiltered =listItems;

        // SqLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(context);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);


    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    listItemsFiltered = listItems;
                } else {
                    List<AttendanceModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (AttendanceModel row : listItems) {

                        // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                        if (row.getName().toUpperCase().contains(charSequence.toString().toUpperCase())||row.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase())) {

                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                    listItemsFiltered = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = listItemsFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                listItemsFiltered = (ArrayList<AttendanceModel>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView name;
        public TextView roll;
        public TextView previous;

        RadioGroup radioAttendance;
        RadioButton radioAttendancePresent,radioAttendanceAbsent;


        public CardView card_view;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAttendanceStudentName);
            roll = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAttendanceStudentRoll);
            previous = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAttendanceStudentPreviousStatus);
            radioAttendance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioAttendance);
            radioAttendancePresent =itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioAttendancePresent);
            radioAttendanceAbsent =itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioAttendanceAbsent);

            //card_view = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.class_card_view); // card view for on click method
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick( View view) {
                    // send selected contact in callback
                    listner.onAttendanceAdapterSelected(listItemsFiltered.get(getAdapterPosition()));  // selecting cardview and position (model)
                }
            });
            radioAttendance.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                    //Toast.makeText(TeacherAttendanceActivity.this, toString(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Toast.makeText(context,"clicked at position"+i+" "+id+""+name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if(radioAttendancePresent.isChecked())
                    {
                        listItems.get(getAdapterPosition()).setAttendance("present");


                    }
                    else {
                        listItems.get(getAdapterPosition()).setAttendance("absent");

                    }

                }
            });


        }


    }


    @Override
    public AttendanceAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.attendance_list, parent, false);
        return new AttendanceAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder  (final AttendanceAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final AttendanceModel listItem = listItemsFiltered.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(listItem.getName());
        holder.roll.setText(listItem.getRoll());
        holder.previous.setText(listItem.getPreviousAttendance());
 
      
    }

    public interface AttendanceAdapterListner {
        void onAttendanceAdapterSelected(AttendanceModel model);  // sending cardview to say the dialoge and model for sending context
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItemsFiltered.size();
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem would be solved by making small changes to your Recycler view adapter, please do not disable recyclable property, this makes your recycler view a glorified list view.

I can see you tried using a sparse boolean array to hold the state of the radio buttons, that is good but you do not need that too. The idea behind using a Sparse boolean array is to keep the state of each item in the recycler view so that when they are recycled you still have a reference to what the state of each item is.

In your adapter you already have something that we can use to know the state, that is the `attendance` property of your model, in that case, you can set the state of your checkboxes by checking if the attendance property is `present` or `absent`.

One more thing about your code is that you are using the `onCheckChangedListener` as a click event handler for your radio button, you should not use this because it responds to all check changed events, even if it is triggered from code and not from user action, so when you bind your view and you set any of your radio buttons as checked or unchecked, it calls this callback.

Here is a modified version of your ViewHolder class that solves this issue by applying the solution above.

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView name;
    public TextView roll;
    public TextView previous;

    RadioGroup radioAttendance;
    RadioButton radioAttendancePresent, radioAttendanceAbsent;


    public CardView card_view;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAttendanceStudentName);
        roll = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAttendanceStudentRoll);
        previous = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAttendanceStudentPreviousStatus);
        radioAttendance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioAttendance);
        radioAttendancePresent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioAttendancePresent);
        radioAttendanceAbsent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioAttendanceAbsent);

        radioAttendancePresent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                radioAttendancePresent.setChecked(true);
                listItems.get(getAdapterPosition()).setAttendance("present");
            }
        });

        radioAttendanceAbsent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                radioAttendanceAbsent.setChecked(true);
                listItems.get(getAdapterPosition()).setAttendance("absent");
            }
        });

    }

    void bind(int position) {
        // use the sparse boolean array to check
        if (listItems.get(position).getAttendance() != null) {
            if (listItems.get(position).getAttendance().equals("present")) {
                radioAttendancePresent.setChecked(true);
            } else if (listItems.get(position).getAttendance().equals("absent")) {
                radioAttendanceAbsent.setChecked(true);
            }
        } else {
            radioAttendance.clearCheck();
        }

        name.setText(listItems.get(position).getName());
        roll.setText(listItems.get(position).getRoll());
        previous.setText(listItems.get(position).getPreviousAttendance());
    }
}
```

Notice that we have separate click listener for each radio button and set the state in the list of items and just check that state when we are binding, also we have removed the `onCheckChangedListener` and the sparse boolean array, one last thing is that we made sure that when there is not state set for the attendance property, we just clear the radio buttons so that no one is selected the code is much simpler and works correctly now.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize your `RadioButton` based on model state like below:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder  (final AttendanceAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final AttendanceModel listItem = listItemsFiltered.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(listItem.getName());
    holder.roll.setText(listItem.getRoll());
    holder.previous.setText(listItem.getPreviousAttendance());

    final String id =listItem.getId();
    final String class_id =listItem.getClassId();


    holder.radioAttendance.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    if(listItem.getAttendance().equalsIgnoreCase("present")) {
        radioAttendancePresent.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        radioAttendancePresent.setChecked(false);
    }

    //Add listener here and remove from holder
    holder.radioAttendance.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            if(holder.radioAttendancePresent.isChecked()) {
                listItemsFiltered.get(position).setAttendance("present");
            } else {
                listItemsFiltered.get(position).setAttendance("absent");
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: no it didn't solve my problem. still selecting some other radio button

Comment: Check my updated answer. Don't forget to remove `radioAttendance.setOnCheckedChangeListener` from holder

Comment: sorry but code showing error. and why did you used if(class_id.equalsIgnoreCase("present")) {..... } class_id has nothing to do in here. edited my code also

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Replaced `class_id` with `listItem.getAttendance()`. Check my updated code